# In an $m \times n$ board there is a path that starts and ends in the same square

Tags: graph-theory

On a $m \times n$ board a path is a succession of squares such that two consecutive squares share one side.

Show that on an $m \times n$ board there is a path that starts and ends in the same square and that goes through all the squares on the board exactly once, if and only if, one of the numbers $m$ or $n$ is even and both are greater than or equal to 2.

I'm lost, I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Some parts of this problem are easy and you should at least sort out the easy parts vs. the hard parts.

Comment: Well, the number of squares certainly has to be even. So either one or both of the sides is even.

Comment: @K.defaoite Why does the number of squares need to be even?

Comment: @Robert Shore There are 4 possible types of moves: right(R), left(L), up (U) and down(D). For a sequence of moves, i.e, strings containing some combination of these 4 letters, to terminate on the same square it started on, it must contain an equal number of "R"s as "L"s and the same for "U"s and "D"s. If we make $a$ "L"s and $b$ "D"s, then the total number of moves is $a+b+a+b=2a+2b=2(a+b)$ which is even.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks.  I figured it out via a coloring argument.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

A path that visits every vertex and begins and ends at the same place is called a Hamiltonian circuit.  So the question is asking you to confirm that this is a necessary and sufficient condition for a Hamiltonian circuit to exist.

You can construct the required Hamiltonian circuit when it exists.  By rotating the board if necessary, we can assume without loss of generality that the board has $m$ rows with $m$ even.  Also assume $n \ge 2$.  Start at the lower left corner of the board and go all the way to the top and then all the way to the right.  Now descend by $1$ row and go as far to the left as possible.  Descend another row and again travel all the way to the right edge of the board.  Lather, rinse, repeat, and since $m$ is even, when you return to the bottom row, you'll close the circuit by returning all the way to the lower left corner.  That proves one direction.

If either dimension is $1$, then there's no path that both enters and leaves the square on either edge of the single row, so no circuit is possible.  So all that's left to show is that no Hamiltonian circuit is possible if both dimensions are odd.

Note that if you color the board as a checkerboard, at each step the path alternates colors.  Note also a Hamiltonian cycle has the same length as the number of squares in the board, so if both dimensions of the board are odd, then a Hamiltonian cycle must have odd length because the board has an odd number of squares.  But that can't happen because that would make it a cycle that begins and ends on opposite colors.

Comment: Not only does show that a path **does not** exist when both $m$ and $n$ are off, but it shows a path **does** exist when either one is even (which was not asked in the question, but is a nice bonus). Well done.

Comment: Both were asked.  Note the "if and only if" phrase in the question.